# cmake failed building project on mac

Tags: macos

I'm trying to build a project on my new macbook which was previously built normally on linux computers.

at first when i run `cmake`, i get a the following:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Performing Test HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME
-- Performing Test HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME - Failed
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   graph
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- -> doxygen not found -> api-doc will not be created
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/folder
```

and then when i run `make`, it works till around 30% and then it stop with this error:

```
/path/to/project/lib/helpers.cpp:555:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gettimeofday'
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/genom.dir/helpers.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/genom.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I looked online, there was some suggestions for changing `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);` to `clock_get_time(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);`

but they didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you provided indicates that `gettimeofday` wasn't included. What `clock_gettime` has to do with it is not possible to say from the information you provided.

A quick search about this yields, that `gettimeofday` should be available (it's  part of POSIX).
**Do you have `#include <sys/time.h>`([Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)) or `#include <sys/types.h>`([SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2165776/461597))?**